# What is the space complexity of below method?

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to understand space complexity for below method. I tried simplest approach myself. Time complexity is O(n). Unable to determine whether space complexity is O(1) or O(n) as I am reassigning a (string) in every iteration.

```
    public boolean anagram2(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() != b.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (a.contains("" + b.charAt(i))) {
                a = a.replace("" + b.charAt(i), "");
            }
        }

        return a.length() == 0;
    }
```

Can you also please explain difference between space complexity and auxiliary space?

Comment: Time complexity is not O(n) here, it is O(A * B), where A and B are lengths of and b respectively. For each char in b, you are checking if a contains that char, which is O(n).

Comment: @NarendraPathai - your understanding is not right. I am using same loop of size n and that loop runs only if lengths of a and b are equal. I am not using two loops.

Comment: @Ram There are more loops hidden in the implementation of `contains` and `replace`. They also count to the run-time.

Comment: had it been StringBuilder, it would have been O(1) but with String used, it would be O(n)

Comment: @abhilash_goyal Using StringBuilder would not have made a difference, since `replace` and `contains` still needs to iterate over the entire string.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood you. I thought you were talking about time complexity. My bad

Answer (score 3):

They are all destroyed at the end, but the space complexity would be the maximum amount of space needed at any point while the algorithm is running.

You're creating a new string for each iteration, using **O(n)** space. Only one of them needs to be kept in memory at a time, so the total space complexity would be **O(n)**.

Answer (score 0):

As they already said, space complexity seems <s>O(1) since no additional variables are used and, even if you reassign a string at each iteration, the previous one is not anymore tracked and gets destroyed at the end of the iteration.</s>

Edit:
After @Henry comment, I thought at it a but more and I agree with him, the space complexity seems O(n) since at each iteration you are creating a new string of variabile length in relation to the previous string and assigning it to a variable.

But, I want to point out that the time complexity is not O(n) as you said. Even if you have a single loop, the methods contains and replace aren't costing only O(1), such methods search / work on the whole string and as such, every time you use one, it costs O(a) where a is the length of the string the method is working on.
For this reason, the cost is more approximable at O(n * n)

Usually for what I remember, search, replace, sum operations on strings does not cost O(1)

Comment: space used (even auxiliary space) is also O(n). It does not matter, that is is garbage collected soon after it was allocated.

Comment: @Henry uhm, after thinking at it a bit more, I agree with you, you are right! Thanks for correcting me, I will edit my answer to reflect the correct answer.